# Formal differences T, T& and T&&

Tags: c++, reference

I'm looking for a normative reference to the Standard.

We can declare a variable of reference type as follows:

```
int a = 5;
int &b = a;
```

Formally, the type of `a` is `int`, but the type of `b` is `int&`. So why can we initialize `int&` with `int`? I was looking for a standard conversion for these types, but it seems there isn't.

Comment: The type of both `a` and `b` is same: `int&`. In your code, both refer to the *same* object in memory.

Comment: @Nawaz Why? Declared type of `a` is `int`. It's obvious from the declaration.

Comment: You're talking about `decltype(a)`, and I'm talking about `decltype((a))`. Noticed the difference? Please read about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize `int&` with `int` because the standard says:

> A variable declared to be a `T&` or `T&&`, that is, “reference to type `T`” (8.3.2), shall be initialized by an object,
>   or function, of type `T` or by an object that can be converted into a `T`.

(N3936, 8.5.3/1)

There is no "standard conversion" from `T` to `T&`, and

> When a parameter of reference type binds directly (8.5.3) to an argument expression, the implicit conversion
>   sequence is the **identity conversion**, unless the argument expression has a type that is a derived class of the
>   parameter type, in which case the implicit conversion sequence is a derived-to-base Conversion (13.3.3.1).

(N3936, 13.3.3.1.4/1; emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you for that answer but could you clarify the following moment, please? If we initiaize a reference in the following way: `int a = 5; int &c = a; int &d = c;` the latter referecnce isn't initialized by an object. Formally it's initialized by a reference is binded to the object, not by the object itself. Since the reference isn't the object we how we can apply that rule to the case I cited here?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv The reference *is* the object. See 5/5. An expression of lvalue reference type is adjusted to be an lvalue of non-reference type.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: You seem to be missing the concept of "the value of an expression". Variables are initialized with values. Values are never references.